# How to create a django model from an existing specific database table?

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models, pycharm

Can I use inspectdb, if so how can I use it in pycharm? I am new to django. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this post that will help you craft a question that is likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To run a Django command in PyCharm you should create a new configuration.
So, first of all click on *Run* in the top bar menu. Then click on *Edit Configuration*.

Now, a new window should be opened which display all your configurations. In the top-right corner you can find a plus (+) symbol, click on it and choose *Django server*.

In this way, you have created a new Django configuration.
Then, you should compile all information that you needed. 
I think that for *inspectdb* command you should insert the following parameters:

1. Custom run command -> inspectdb
2. Additional options -> only if you want, if i remember well you can specify the table name
3. Environment variables
4. Python interpreter

At the end click on *Apply* and *Ok*

To run the command click on *Run* and choose the new command.